# Función con puppeteer pasándole por parámetros los id y clases del DOM

Tags: javascript, nodejs, puppeteer

Estoy intentando crear una función para reutilizarla y optimizar código.

Tengo este ejemplo que seria completamente funcional:

```
const euromillones = await page.evaluate(() => {
const ul_euro = document.querySelector('#qa_ultResult-combination-actMainNumbers-EMIL');
return Array.from(
  ul_euro.querySelectorAll(
    
    ".c-ultimo-resultado__combinacion-li--euromillones"
  )
)
  .map((x) => x.textContent)
  .slice(0, 5);
});
```

Esta es la función que estoy creando para hacerlo:

```
async function obtenerResultados({item1,item2,limite=5}){
  console.log(item1, item2, limite);
  await page.evaluate(item1,item2,limite,() => {
    const ul_euro = document.querySelector("#"+item1);
    return Array.from(
      ul_euro.querySelectorAll(
        "."+item2
      )
    )
    .map((x) => x.textContent)
    .slice(0, limite);
  });
}
```

Y la llamaría de esta forma:

```
const euromillones = await obtenerResultados({item1:"qa_ultResult-combination- 
  actMainNumbers-EMIL",item2:"c-ultimo-resultado__combinacion-li--euromillones",limite:5});
```

Pero no consigo que funcione, creo saber en que parte esta fallando, que seria cuando le paso a evaluate todos esos parámetros junto a la promesa, el error que me salta seria el siguiente:

> (node:34556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: qa_ultResult is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale la solución era simple se debía añadir las variables al final de la función de esta forma:

```
async function obtenerResultados({item1, item2, limite=5}){
  euromillones = await page.evaluate((item1, item2, limite) => {
    console.log(item1, item2, limite);
    const ul_euro = document.querySelector("#"+item1);
    return Array.from(
      ul_euro.querySelectorAll(
        "."+item2
      )
    )
    .map((x) => x.textContent)
    .slice(0, limite);
  }, item1, item2, limite);
}
```